# How to load existing .db file in HTML5

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I need to load existing .db file in my phone Gap application on Android . This below given code is creating new database

```
var db = window.openDatabase("DBName", "1.0", "description", 5*1024*1024); 
db.transaction(function(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test", [], successCallback, errorCallback);
});
```

but i want to load my existing database . But I don`t how to do that.

plz help me with the code .

Comment: the openDatabase function should open an existing DB if it exists by that name&version. Try setting the version field empty ("")

Comment: i tried passing empty ("") version number and database name as DatabasePawan.db and placed my db file in the memory then also database is not loading and it is creating new database with database.db name as attached here in screen shot http://i41.tinypic.com/2pt9au1.png . plz give me some more suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this post.

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)

Comment: thanks it helped me to understand the phoneGap database concept and i was able to do it.

Comment: Above given link by simon helped me to use existing .db file in phoneGap Android project, but now i want to achieve same task in my phoneGap blackberry project. could someone plz give me some idea.

Comment: i used the above link to copy existing database, but for android version 4.4+ it is not working.
Can any one suggest me the solution/idea.
window.openDatabase("DBName", "1.0", "description", 5*1024*1024);  
window.openDatabase() Replaces my database file with default.